# Stephen Hawking's theory of future backreaction

Tags: quantum-field-theory, specific-reference

Several years ago, New Scientist featured an article on a new theory by Stephen Hawking that involved the future having some effect or "backreaction" on the present.

As it would be very tedious and time consuming to root through several years of back issues to find it again, I was hoping someone might be able to provide a reference, or just put me on the right track.

I tried a search myself, but could find nothing on the arXiv. I thought for a moment it might be ["Cosmology from the Top Down"](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0305562); but although that is interesting, it doesn't match what I recall of the article.

Please note, I'm not interested in starting a discussion of the merits or otherwise of this theory, merely seeking a reference.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to leave this open because specific reference questions are on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, found it! Searching through scanned back issues of scientific magazines is damned time consuming, because so many interesting articles need re-reading ;-)

The article I was thinking of is from New Scientist 2006-04-22, vol 190, no 2548, page 28, "Mr Hawking's Flexiverse". The basic theme wasn't quite how I remembered it, but somewhat related.

The article didn't reference the original paper, or not that I noticed; but from the timing of its appearance I imagine it must have been based on the paper "Populating the landscape: A Top down approach". S.W. Hawking (Cambridge U., DAMTP), Thomas Hertog (CERN). CERN-PH-TH-2006-022. Feb 2006. 22 pp. Published in Phys.Rev. D73 (2006) 123527, listed on Hawking's web page at http://www.hawking.org.uk/publications.html

Anyway, that answers my question. So thanks everyone for helping, or wanting to help even if you weren't able to!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe ["Backwards to the future"](https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg16522244.600-backwards-to-the-future/) (2000-02-06) is the reference that you're looking for?

I haven't read it, as it is behind the paywall, so this may be irrelevant.

Comment: Not sure: that article's about Schulman's work.  [Here](http://people.clarkson.edu/~lschulma/2008InfluenceOfFutureSHPM.pdf) is a reference, but no mention of Hawking.

Comment: While this may look like a link-only answer, the question is explicitly asking for just a reference.  So, the provided link is an actual answer.

Comment: Actually, dunno what the policy here might be.  The question is explicitly seeking just a reference and not discussion, so there wouldn't seem to be anything intrinsically wrong with just providing a link.  But then again, apparently the link wasn't read, so it's a guess.  So perhaps it's not problematic so much for being a link-only answer, but for being a guess... but then that'd just make it wrong and down-vote worthy, right?  Hah confusing case.

Comment: @Nat No, that's not how reference-request questions work. "Before answering, please see [our policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4698/84967) on resource recommendation questions. Please write substantial answers that detail the style, content, and prerequisites of the book, paper or other resource. Explain the nature of the resource so that readers can decide which one is best suited for them rather than relying on the opinions of others. Answers containing only a reference to a book or paper will be removed!"

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform The linked answer says that [tag:specific-reference] questions are different; does the same policy apply to them?

Comment: @Nat The philosophy is essentially the same: "Please write substantial answers that detail the style, **content**...". The alternative -- to post titles of papers if they seem to be related -- is useless, especially when you have not read them.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform *the philosophy is essentially the same* no it's not. A spec-ref answer should *give a complete list of the bibliographic information for the reference(s) being requested, or at least enough information to uniquely identify them* (as per the info tab on it) There is no need for writing any BS about "style, content & prereqs".